# Reduce image file size without resize and quality lose

Tags: image-optimization

In a site i am daily uploading around 100+ images that have taken from digital cameras, a single image file have an average file size of around 3MB. It needs high amount of disk space in server. If i can reduce the average size below 1MB i can upload more images in the current space.
I have tried many online image optimizers, but all of them can't helped me to reduce below at least 1.5MB.

Comment: i have found a online tool for this, this site optimize images well http://jpeg-tools.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jpeg-tools.com](http://jpeg-tools.com/) is a best site to optimize images, they accept a maximum of 20MB image files. You will never face any quality lose.